# Modal popup showing on the wrong monitor

Tags: 11.10, multiple-monitors, dialog

On Ubuntu 11.10, I'm seeing modals from many applications show up on a different monitor from their parent application. In this example, Firefox, the application on the right most monitor, has popped up a modal dialog in the center monitor.

[image: screen shot]

You'll notice that it is not just on the wrong monitor, it's also positioned horizntally against the left edge of that monitor. Vertically, it's centered.

This happens for at least Firefox, Eclipse and gedit modals. It seems like it's all applications. It doesn't matter which monitor the parent application is on, the  modals are always on the left edge of the center monitor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug which has beenreported to the developers. You can mark it as affecting you from its bug page.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/754508

Comment: There is a workaround on the linked bug history (using compizconfig-settings-manager) that seemed to work pretty well for me. It was posted by Jordon Bedwell on 2012-07-16.

Comment: But the workaround seems to be gone in 12.10. OTOH, there should be a permanent fix in the up and coming 13.04

Answer (score 0):

The primary and the secondary display are one whole display. The modal dialog is constructed to be shown center on the screen. I suppose that this center is the "border" between the both monitors..this is the only one reason i have :) But i want all screens and dialogs to be shown on the primary screen only, too.